# What is the maximum value of $n$ for which $x = (n)^x$

Tags: number-theory

This equation just came to my mind, I tried solving it but can't find any solution to this problem. Can anyone please tell what is the process to approach this problem?

Comment: It would help if you would be more precise about the question. What is $x$, for example? Also, to get useful feedback, you should enclose your thoughts about the question. What have you tried?

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to the world of [Lambert function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function) !

The solution of $x=n^x$ is given by
$$x=-\frac{W(-\log (n))}{\log (n)}$$ and, in the real domain, $W(t)$ is defined if $t \geq -\frac 1e$ which implies $n\leq e^{-e}$.

Answer (score 0):

Considering the equation $$x=n^x$$ and taking the logarithm on both sides we get
$$\frac{\ln(x)}{x}=\ln(n)$$ so $$n=e^{\frac{\ln(x)}{x}}$$ now you can use calculus for $$e^{\frac{\ln(x)}{x}}$$